# these demos: http://www.ape-project.org/demos/ are not working on my machine

Tags: javascript, connection-pooling

Does they work on yours? tested in firefox and chrome. Probably i have some problem with a firewall settings or something?

Comment: Nope, the demos are just down right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it did not work for a few months at the beginning of 2011. It's back up now though (since March, actually), and should be working again. Just to give some closure to this question.